# "Call to undefined function" using "use function" in php 5.6.2

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I don't know if I'm asking a stupid question. But I have the following problem when using namespaced function in php 5.6.2. 
I'm following this manual page: 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

In the example it says:

```
// aliasing a function (PHP 5.6+)
use function My\Full\functionName as func;
//some other examples in between;
func(); // calls function My\Full\functionName
```

So I tried this: 
file1.php

```
<?php
namespace A;
function func() {
    return "Hohoho!";
}
?>
```

index.php

```
use function A\func as hohoho;
echo hohoho();
```

PHP gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function A\func()
```

I am very confused.

Comment: Have you included `file1.php` inside `index.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `file1.php` inside `index.php`.

```
include 'file1.php';
```